# Django 'Like' functionality for a post

Tags: python, database, django

I am implementing a like button for posts (Using a clustom Like model and the pre-defined User model from django.contrib.auth).

Would appreciate hearing how I can improve this code. Also, I am struggeling with loading in the last state of every like button with the correct highlighting (liked or not liked) if the user reloads the page.

Thanks in advance

post.html:

```
<div class="jumbotron post p-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class='post-text'>{{ post.text }}</span>
        <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <footer>
          ~
          <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          {{ post.author }}
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <i style="font-size: 300%;" class="like-btn fa fa-thumbs-o-up center-vertical btn-like-post" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

views.py:

```
def already_liked_post(user, post_id):

    post= Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    return Like.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).exists()

def like_button_clicked(request, post_id):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

        if not already_liked_post(request.user, post_id):
            Like.objects.create(user=request.user, post=post, timestamp=datetime.now())
        else:
            Like.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post).delete()

        return redirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        return redirect(reverse('login'))
```

index.html:

```
{% for post in posts %}
   {% include 'includes/post.html' %}
{% endfor %}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){

    $('.like-btn').on('click', function(){
      likePost(this);
    });

    function likePost(thumb){

      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        // Visual like button highlighting
        $(thumb).toggleClass('btn-like-post')

        // route: /like/(id)
        // Take the index of the current like-button and add
        // 1 to it (so it starts at 1) to match the primary-key
        // of the database

        id = $('.like-btn').index(thumb)+1
        var url = '/like/' + id.toString()
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
          method: 'POST',
          success: function(){
          }
        })
      {% else %}
        window.location='/login'
      {% endif %}
    }

  });
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.text} ~ {self.author}'

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} likes \'{self.post.text}\''
```

Comment: first, I will suggest to not create/delete object from your db like you did. `if not already_liked_post(request.user, post_id): create` if not `delete` too much hits